# Table data doesn't go on separate rows

Tags: php, html, html-table

I grab data from my server and want them to display like this:

[image: http://gyazo.com/3ed9349af4a0c3eb9fe9492b74104526]

And instead, this happens:

[image: http://gyazo.com/2c7960ff62c35723b444545476e1d99c]

I use PHP for the values:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
            <td>
                Player Name
            </td>
            <td >
                PK Level
            </td>
            <td>
                Kills
            </td>
            <td>
                Experience
            </td>           
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td >
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM high ORDER BY Runecraftlvl DESC LIMIT 20");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                          echo $row['Runecraftlvl'];
                          echo "<br />";
                          }
                    ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM high ORDER BY Runecraftlvl DESC LIMIT 20");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                          echo $row['Runecraftlvl'];
                          echo "<br />";
                          }
                    ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM high ORDER BY Runecraftlvl DESC LIMIT 20");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                          echo $row['Runecraftlvl'];
                          echo "<br />";
                          }
                    ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM high ORDER BY Runecraftlvl DESC LIMIT 20");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                          echo $row['Runecraftlvl'];
                          echo "<br />";
                          }
                    ?>
            </td>           
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Why is this happening? How can I make the data go on separate rows, 4 data each row?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I have no idea on how to convert it into PDO

Comment: Did you even look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)?

Comment: First, think about why it's happening... What does the code say? What do you do with the `while`-statement?

Comment: I think it's because the PHP code prints all of the data on the same row. But the question is, how do I make it go on separate rows.

Comment: Think about this: should you get one list on paper, how would you go about writing it down the way you want to?

Comment: Well I have no idea, therefore I am asking for some hints.

Comment: You count 1, 2, 3, 4 and start a new row...

Comment: Yes but the PHP pastes ALL of the data at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving away any code, I'll give you a few hints.

Since you're not getting my point... You should add a **counter** yourself, and check whether or not you have to close the row.

But... Because you want 4 values in one cell, you will have to write them to **temporary variables**. You would need 4 variables: **player_name**, **pk_level**, **kills** and **experience**. When you've read out every 4th row of your query result, write them to the table.

`($counter % 4) == 0` will be the main if-clause in your code. This will be `true` whenever the remainder of the division `$counter / 4` is 0.

Also remember: you only need to **perform your query once**.

Give it a try first, and let us know what you come up with.

Comment: Well thanks, Ive done it this way:

    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `high` ORDER BY `Runecraftlvl` DESC LIMIT 20");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr><td>{$row["playerName"]}</td><td>{$row["Runecraftlvl"]}</td><td>{$row["kills"]}</td><td>{$row["Runecraftxp"]}</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>